# Ionic 3 native plugin of sms not working on my device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3 and my device is 4.4.2 android.

Setup:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sms-plugin
npm install --save @ionic-native/sms@4
```

I have add to app.module

import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';

providers: [..., SMS]

home.ts

```
...
import { SMS } from '@ionic-native/sms';

...
constructor(..., private sms: SMS){}

sendSMS(){
this.sms.send('0030699999999', 'sos')
}
```

home.html

```
<button ion-button block (click)="sendSMS()" margin-top color="dark">SMS</button>
```

I install the apk to my phone with below command:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

When I am pressing the button, my app breaks and exit, without sending a message.

I tried to remove platform android and added again, but nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put a send_sms permission in manifest file (android).
Check in my phone v 4.4.2.
I didn't check it in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Allow from app settings on your phone